# Identify unwanted drone

Tags: regulations

Sometimes  during night  a drone is hovering near my windows, especially while we are sleeping or my wife is breastfeeding our daughter. You can imagine how happy she is having a stalker recording such moments.

I don't want to shoot at it, neither with water nor anything else.
Nevertheless I would like to inhibit this drone at least a bit.
The 2 solutions I can think of are:

1. jam the signal
2. identify the remote.

Solution 1 is expensive, probably illegal and could bring hazards to things and people under the jammed drone.

Therefore I would like to go for the second solution. What are the options I have for identify a drone and or a remote of a drone?

I'm pretty sure I can use some war-driving technique, but I'm not sure to what I have to search for. How can I identify the remote control and its operator?

Comment: What is your jurisdiction? as remoteID comes into play into the USA, the pilot must identify themselves and may not fly beyond line of sight. This means if they can see you, you can see them. Otherwise they are violating UAS laws (note I am not american so cannot detail this). The short answer is that it's not possible to identify the transmitter without _very_ expensive equipment

Comment: Italy here, there should be something similar, but as you can imagine, I guess that no pilot will keep the line of sight or something. Actually I come up with a different solution, the drone seems to have an wifi Access point, so I can identify at least the name and the MAC address of the AP, then I'll make some research in the streets near to find out where is the client of that AP.
Not the best solution, but with this data I can move the practice to law enforcers.

Comment: Capture the drone, if the owner goes after you, you already find out who he is. But isn't correct way, the correct way is call the police and take the necessary measures according to the law of your country

Comment: Lol, the drone is hovering too far away to be catched without some aid, but I've thought a different solution actually: A laptop with a monitor mode wifi, everytime a new Access point is found, the db power and date/time is logged continuosly for 5 minutes, so I've a bunch of Drones AP that are passing near, with this information I'll try to go to the police (I bet that nothing will happen, but I can continue experimenting with the data I gather).

Comment: "too far to be caught without aid" A heavy fishing line with a small weight on the end can be thrown at it. The machine will happily tangle itself in fishing line and disable at the same time. A cast net would do even better

Answer (score 1):

Call the police and report a peeping tom.  Your state, county, or city municipality will have voyeur laws.  Of course, most actions performed in your home, with a window un-curtained would likely be considered in-plain-view in the eyes of the law as you would not have an expectation of privacy.  Close the curtains at night- call the police.  You likely have other neighbors being pestered.  The more reports the more likely it will be to identify the incel since their house will be at the geometric center of the complaints.

Shooting drones with firearms in the national airspace is a felony.  This could result in your inability to possess firearms in the USA.  The same would be true if you tossed a line at the drone.  Jamming FCC radio frequencies as a citizen is also illegal.

Placing or hanging fishing line near your proopertys as 'art' is your right as a land owner as you have the right to control the space near your land (unless the use violates FAA rules like a tall antenna).  Fishing line would be impossible to see in the dark from a drone video feed.  If this art happened to entangle and crash a drone being operated in an unsafe manner that is not your problem.  A crash like this would subject the pilot to trespassing laws since there is now debris on your land, and FAA rules for failing to operate safely (if the suspect came looking for the drone).